# Is there a way to disable android market?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to disable android market ? Say for a device admin or anyone for that matter ? How does ATT do it ? Have they asked mobile manufactures to modify the Android src accordingly ?

**Edit :** Can this be done on non-rooted device ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain AT&T didn't disable the Marketplace, but rather disabled the ability to side load apps.  Currently the only way to install apps on an AT&T phone is through the marketplace (there are other ways, but not officially sanctioned by AT&T)  That was the reason for the whole stink about the Amazon AppStore not available for AT&T users.  I assume you are talking about users phones and not a custom device so I think you are out of luck on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't modify the source.

The Market is just another app, but its typically stored in the `/system/app` directory which is read-only without root access.  If you root the device, or if you're a manufacturer you simply need to remove the `vending.apk` from `/system/app`.