# How does installing an Android app from the market differ from sideloading via web download or adb?

Tags: android, adb

I know of four ways to install an Android application on a rooted phone:

1. Install via the Android market
2. Enable 'Unknown sources' in Settings->Applications and download an .apk from the web
3. Enable 'USB debugging' in Settings->Applications->Development and adb install
4. Enable 'USB debugging' in Settings->Applications->Development and adb push to /data/app or /system/app

What are the major differences between these options? If I delete Market/Vending and PackageInstaller apps, will I still be able to sideload from adb? For the purposes of this question assume I have no Market apps on the phone.

Comment: Just one thing: AFAIK the first 3 ways can also be used in a non rooted device

Comment: I find a good variation on option 2 is to just email the apk as an attachment to an email address that is being checked on the phone, such as a gmail account, which many android users have already setup. Upon opening the attachment, the option will be given to install the app. You don't need to root the phone to do this either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary differences in the install are the upgrade paths.  Market installed apps notify you when there is an update (via the market).  Manually installed apps (2-4) depend on the app to notify you which may or may not be supported in any given app, or you can always manually check the source of the app to see if there are available updates.  I believe apps installed via adb push need a reboot in order for them to be properly registered as installed.

If you decide to delete MarketUpdater.apk, I believe the only issue will be auto-update notifications of previously market installed apps as previously mentioned.  If you want to delete the Market App itself, vs the updater, Vending.apk is what you are looking for.

I would not remove the PackageInstaller.  Its used to install (and register) apps regardless of install method.  At one point I had accidentally replaced a commandline tool PackageInstaller uses with an incompatible busybox alternative.  When I tried to manually install apps, PackageInstaller would barf.  I fixed the commandline tool program, but the point is that PackageInstaller was used during manual installs.

Comment: When you deleted PackageInstaller, how were you trying to install apps? Web download, adb push, adb install? Also, I updated the question to narrow down a bit and include some of your points (updates, Vending, etc).

Comment: I was using adb install.  PackageInstaller is also (eventually) used however for "adb push" installs.  The adb push part works, but when the system reboots PackageInstaller is needed to complete the install. Thats the main difference between push and install.  install registers the app immediately with PackageInstaller, push depends on a reboot for PackageInstaller to complete the installation.  push is nice if you want to push a bunch of apps at the same time (eg for restoring from backup), but install is better if you want them immediately accessible, eg for debugging.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks again. I'd be interested in any pointers to docs on this, if you know of any.

Answer (score 0):

- The google push notification called as Cloud to device messaging(c2dm) requires the Market app to be present on the device in order to work whether or not applications are installed via the Market.
- Also do take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516895/is-there-a-way-to-disable-android-market).

Comment: I'm fine without c2dm, and I know which apks to uninstall to get rid of the market. Bigger question is what is the difference of doing adb install X versus adb push /system/app/X